# Graphical tool for creating Deb packages

Tags: software-recommendation, packaging, deb

Are there any graphical tools for creating ubuntu/debian packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's **[Ubucompiler](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/):, but development has ceased:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Description:**

An easy software to ubuntu, debian, linux mint to compile, make, install and create a .deb package

On the other hand, on [this wepupd8.org page](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html), a critic of Ubucompiler reads as follows:

> Ubucompilator  does not add the necessary Build-Depends to the Debian
>   control file so yes, the .deb package can be created with
>   Ubucompilator, but you cannot use the source code to say Launchpad so
>   it can be build for different architectures, etc. Also, the packages
>   are not signed and so on, so that's not the proper way of creating a
>   .deb file

Comment: Ubucompiler depends on gambas2 which was superseded by gambas3 in current Ubuntu distributions. The project has last seen any action back in 2010, so while it might have been an option back then, it should probably be considered obsolete and broken today.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `debomatic`. It's already in Ubuntu's package archives:

```
sudo apt-get install debomatic
```

It provides a simple tool to automate build of source packages with limited user interaction and a simple configuration. It has some useful features such as automatic update of pbuilder, automatic scan and selection of source packages to build and modules support.

It is meant to help developers to build their packages without worrying too much of compilation, since it will run in background and no user feedback is required during the whole process.

The project is developed by a Ubuntu developer: https://launchpad.net/debomatic

Comment: There is nothing graphical about debomatic, nor does it help with creating the packaging... It's more of a build daemon/repository.

Answer (score 3):

[GiftWrap](https://launchpad.net/giftwrap) is another option.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Ubucompilator](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/) in its updated version 1.0 beta.
A short usage introduction video can be found here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/ubucompilator-easy-deb-creator-10-beta.html

Comment: This seems like a great start.  However, if you don't already know how to do the packaging manually, the interface is baffling.

Answer (score 2):

Also you should check **[Debreate](http://debreate.sourceforge.net/)**

**[Description:](https://sourceforge.net/projects/debreate/)**

Debreate is a utility to aid in building Debian packages (.deb). The goal is to make packaging for Debian based Linux distributions more appealing with an easy to use interface for creating distributable archives of applications, artwork, media, and more.
[image: Control dialog for Debreate]

Features:

- Changelog editor Script editor (pre-install, post-install,
  pre-remove, post-remove);
- System menu launcher editor;
- Dependencies, pre-depends, conflicts, breaks, suggests, recommends, enhances, and replaces editor;
- md5checksum;
- Building a package from a preexisting build tree.

[Opendesktop.org link](http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=101776)

I am using for my CarMusTy distribution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

There's **[deb-creator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/deb-creator/)**:
[image: Screenshot from https://sourceforge.net/projects/deb-creator/]

**Description:**

Deb-Creator is a tool to quickly create Debian packages. The program provides a simple graphical user interface written in C++ using Qt Creator. It uses the dpkg command in Linux to build the final Debian package.

**Features:**

- Automatically generates control file (completed)
- Allows you to manually edit control file (complete)
- Uses dpkg to build Debian packages (complete)
- Converts RPM packages to Debian packages using Alien (not done)
- Convert Debian packages to RPM (not done)
- Create md5sums (not done)

Answer (score 1):

You could check [Deb Cup](https://github.com/pavreh/deb-cup).

Deb Cup is a GUI tool for creating deb packages and uploading to a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pavreh/ppa
sudo apt install deb-cup -y
deb-cup
```

[image: deb-cup interface]

Usage:

- Select Project Folder
- Create Debian Directory
- Add dependancies to `control`'s `Depends:`
- Create *.deb binary

*DISCLAIMER: I am the developer of Deb Cup*

Comment: You could improve your answer in various ways; describe its advantages, list essential steps, add a link to the ppa.

Comment: @Pavel deb-cup is awesome. Please add the details I added to your answer to the readme.md on github so more people can learn about your awesome tool!

Answer (score 0):

There's **[Debianpackagemaker](https://code.google.com/archive/p/debianpackagemaker/), but development has ceased:**
[image: Instal Structure tab]
[image: Log tab]

**Description:**

A simple and straight forward debian package maker.
DebianPackageMaker is a simple user interface/tool to make a debian package easier and straightforward to use and deploy your linux application to any debian based distro.

You can build debian packages using two modes:

**Target Mode**

- Manually specify the installation directory and the files to be installed in the target installation directory.

**Source Mode**

- Debian Package Maker will configure the source for you, compile them and then build a package using the target rules.
- Configure/autogen scripts and Makefile/rules is required for DPM to automate the whole process for you.

Provides user interface for package information that will be used as control file to create a debian based package.

It also provides a different tabs for adding package relations:

- Dependencies
- Pre-dependencies
- Recommends
- Suggests
- Breaks
- Conflicts
- Replaces
- Provides

Can add scripts like postins, changelogs, etc, and it's straight forward to use.