# GUI for packaging and uploading files to Launchpad as .deb

Tags: gui, debian

Is there a GUI for packaging and uploading a file to the Ubuntu repository?

No command-line stuff with the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is GUI for packaging. You can find some in this old answer: [Graphical tool for creating Deb packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8055/graphical-tool-for-creating-deb-packages)

But to upload to Launchpad, no.

Anyway, it's easy and you can do with a simple command.

The only caveat: first time only, you need to create SSH keys, register at Launchpad, etc: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html

Then, after create your Launchpad repo, no GUI is required, really simple:

```
dput ppa:<launchpad_user>/<repo> <package>_source.changes
```

Comment: Just one additional note: you'll upload to Launchpad **not** the `.deb` file, but the `.changes` one.